# Best way to retrieve pen pressure value from a Wacom Intuos M for a 64bit SFML drawing application on Win7/64bit?

Tags: c++, windows-7, 64-bit, sfml, wacom

iam looking for a lightweight solution to retrieve pen pressure from a wacom tablet.
My system is win7 64bit and the application is an SFML c++ 64bit program.
I found that wintab seems to be the industry standard but its only 32bit.
Also i found MS Ink, but iam not sure if this makes sense since i wrote my own brush/pen drawing
program already.
I would just need the realtime pen pressure data. XY i get already from mouse coordinates in SFML.

Comment: Doesn't Wacom [6.3.38-2](https://cdn.wacom.com/u/productsupport/drivers/win/professional/releasenotes/Windows_6.3.38.html) work under Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: Yes, i run this driver on my win7 x64 system and it works well.
But i need to grab the pen pressure value for my c++ program in some way.

Comment: Then you'll need to use the [Wintab docs](https://developer-docs.wacom.com/display/DevDocs/Wintab+docs), which has sample code.

Comment: @Elyay ,
Here the docs say..Quote: "The central component of the system is the WINTAB module, WINTAB.DLL [Wacom supports Win32 systems with Wintab32.dll.], which provides application interface services, and to which one or more device drivers connect."
So my question is: Can i access/use this Wintab32.dll and the example code in a 64bit application??

Comment: `dumpbin /headers C:\Windows\System32\Wintab32.dll` says it is 64-bit, and `dumpbin /headers C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wintab32.dll` says it is 32-bit.

Comment: Okay. So in other words this means that there is a 64bit AND a 32bit version available, although they are both named Wintab32.dll.
Interesting and confusing naming conventions for beginners. 
Thank you very much for your help! Its much appreciated!
So i can finally use the 64bit dll in my 64bit application then. Great! :)